# pickerInput default select all choices

Tags: r, shiny

I have about a dozen pickerInputs, and each time I run my shiny app, everything is set to nothing selected. I have to manually select everything before the output works which is a little annoying. Is there a way for pickerInput to default to "select all" each time the app runs?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `selected` argument of `pickerInput`. Just pass all your choices to `selected`, which will choose everything when the app initializes. Setting `action-box` option to `True` will also build **Select All** & **Deselect All** buttons by default, which would improve your current workflow. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "my_input",
    label = "TEST",
    choices = 1:10,    # provide choices - integers from 1 to 10
    selected = 1:10,   # select - integers from 1 to 10 
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),   # build buttons for collective selection
    multiple = T
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This function is really great, but just at the moment (Jan 2021) the dropdown menu won't close. For those who tried this answer and are getting frustrated with this issue, [there is a dev version of shiny for a fix](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/346#issuecomment-768372893)

Comment: I had to use ``options = pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)`` in order for the buttons to appear (otherwise there was no error, but also no buttons). I guess this really depends on the version.