# updatePickerInput default select all choices

Tags: r, shiny

I know that there is a very similar question on StackExchange ([pickerInput default select all choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851127/pickerinput-default-select-all-choices)), however, the solution can not be applied to my problem.
I have a updatePickerInput which is based on two Inputs. on the updatePickerInput I have the selectAll and clearAll buttons from shinyWidgets. I want selectAll to be the default, but since it is dynamically, I dont know how to pass my choices into the selected option.

Here is my relevant ui code:

```
radioButtons(inputId = 'selected_group', label = 'group', choices = '')
```

This is my observeEvent code:

```
observeEvent(c(input$selected_tab,input$selected_group),{
    req(input$selected_group)

    updatePickerInput(
        session,
        'selected_subgroup',
        choices = df %>%
            filter(tab == input$selected_tab) %>%
            filter(group == input$selected_group) %>%
            select(subgroup) %>%
            distinct(subgroup) %>%
            arrange(subgroup) %>%
            .[[1]]
    )
})
```

Comment: Pass the same filtered `df` you are using for your choices to `selected`?

Comment: That df is filtered later on in an reactive() statement. Here it is unfiltered.

Comment: Please see the example in my answer below for clarifcation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have all options selected dynamically you'll need to pass the same information to `updatePickerInput`'s `choices` and `selected` arguments:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(shinyWidgets)

statesDF <- data.frame(region = state.region, name = state.name, area = state.area, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = 'selected_group', label = 'group', choices = unique(statesDF$region)),
  pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_subgroup', label = 'subgroup', choices = NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filteredChoices <- reactive({
    statesDF$name[statesDF$region == input$selected_group]
  })

  observeEvent(filteredChoices(), {
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = 'selected_subgroup', label = 'subgroup', choices = filteredChoices(), selected = filteredChoices())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```